# How do I compare multiple vector of structs for similar names efficiently?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a program for my wife to help us try to decide which medical schools that she should apply for. However, I have run into a problem where I am trying to extract schools that show up in the top 20 results in 4 different cases.

For example, in one of those cases I take the median income of the city, and divide it by the average house price in the city. That returns a double, and then I create a new vector and then sort that vector based on that number from highest to lowest. And I do similar actions to the 3 other vectors in my pool with different cases applied.

I know I can just brute force this and extract the names with nested for loops, but I am curious to know if there is a way to do it quickly and efficiently. This is my attempt so far. (Note, this is just an example, my actual code has 30 schools in it).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Schools
{
    Schools(std::string n = "", double h = 0.0, double t = 0.0, int r = 0, int w = 0) : name(n), housing(h), tuition(t), rank(r), weight(w){};
    std::string name;
    double housing;
    double tuition;
    int rank;
    int weight;
};

void load(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> &v, std::string n, double h, double t, int r, int w)
{
    auto newSchool = std::make_shared<Schools>(n,h,t,r,w);
    v.emplace_back(newSchool);
}

void init(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> &schools)
{
    load(schools,"School1",40.3,20.0,3,6);
    load(schools,"School2",10.3,10.4,5,1);
    load(schools,"School3",33.3,23.5,1,2);
    load(schools,"School4",8.5,15.5,4,8);
}

auto findIntersection(auto &a, auto &b)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> in;
    std::set_intersection(begin(a),end(a),begin(b),end(b),std::back_inserter(in));
    return in;
}

auto findCommon(auto &housing, auto &tuition, auto &rank, auto &weight)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> inCommon;
    inCommon = findIntersection(housing,tuition);
    inCommon = findIntersection(inCommon,rank);
    inCommon = findIntersection(inCommon,weight);
    return inCommon;
}

bool compareHM(const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &a, const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &b)
{
    return a->housing < b->housing;
}

bool compareT(const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &a, const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &b)
{
    return a->tuition < b->tuition;
}

bool compareRank(const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &a, const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &b)
{
    return a->rank > b->rank;
}

bool compareWeight(const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &a, const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &b)
{
    return a->weight > b->weight;
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> schools;
    init(schools);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> sortByHousing = schools;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> sortByTuition = schools;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> sortByRank = schools;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> sortByWeight = schools;

    std::sort(begin(sortByHousing),end(sortByHousing), compareHM);
    std::sort(begin(sortByTuition),end(sortByTuition), compareT);
    std::sort(begin(sortByRank),end(sortByRank), compareRank);
    std::sort(begin(sortByWeight),end(sortByWeight), compareWeight);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Schools>> commonSchools = findCommon(sortByHousing,sortByTuition,sortByRank,sortByWeight);

    for (auto && e: commonSchools)
    {
        std::cout << e->name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I run into a problem when I try to use `std::set_intersection`, and then I quickly realized that I cannot do something like `begin(a)->name`. Again, I am trying to extract common names that show up in each of the 4 cases that I have. How do I go about implementing this? Is my idea of `std::set_intersection` not too far off?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is an example of one of my `functionThatCompares`

```
bool compareTuition(const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &a, const std::shared_ptr<Schools> &b)
{
    return a->tuition < b->tuition;
}
```

EDIT 2: Example Output

```
The top 20 sorted by Median/House are:
Name of Institution                               Median/House Price  Tuition Over 8 Years     Has Space Industry? Score

University of Alabama                             0.463577            0.722279                 1                   0.641825
University of Maryland                            0.38124             0.722617                 1                   0.527583
Johns Hopkins Univerty School of Medicine         0.38124             0.606103                 1                   0.629002
Indiana University                                0.335939            0.501944                 0                   0.669276
Ohio State University                             0.32499             0.610704                 1                   0.532156
Perelman School of Medicine                       0.26908             0.653143                 1                   0.411977
Duke University School of Medicine                0.246991            0.66683                  1                   0.370395
University of Wisconsin                           0.226581            0.64686                  0                   0.350278
Chicago Medical School                            0.221883            0.648157                 0                   0.342329
Northwestern University                           0.221883            0.677341                 0                   0.32758
Case Western Reserve                              0.211817            0.536384                 1                   0.394898
Emory University                                  0.206169            0.576814                 1                   0.357427
Geisel School of Medicine                         0.205529            0.71526                  0                   0.287349
University of Massachusetts                       0.19562             0.64686                  1                   0.302414
Medical University of SC                          0.185816            0.354728                 0                   0.523827
University of North Carolina                      0.176684            0.6637                   0                   0.26621
University of Michigan Medical School             0.158465            0.637237                 1                   0.248675
Rutgers New Jersey Medical School                 0.140412            0.722115                 0                   0.194446
University of Utah                                0.140142            0.311285                 0                   0.450205
Georgetown University                             0.128883            0.604001                 1                   0.213382

The top 20 sorted by Tuition are:
Name of Institution                               Median/House Price  Tuition Over 8 Years     Has Space Industry? Score

University of Utah                                0.140142            0.311285                 0                   0.450205
Medical University of SC                          0.185816            0.354728                 0                   0.523827
University of California, LA                      0.07633             0.47547                  1                   0.160536
Indiana University                                0.335939            0.501944                 0                   0.669276
University of California, SD                      0.109214            0.531397                 1                   0.205523
Case Western Reserve                              0.211817            0.536384                 1                   0.394898
Emory University                                  0.206169            0.576814                 1                   0.357427
Icahn School of Medicine                          0.0822029           0.585946                 1                   0.140291
Georgetown University                             0.128883            0.604001                 1                   0.213382
Johns Hopkins Univerty School of Medicine         0.38124             0.606103                 1                   0.629002
Ohio State University                             0.32499             0.610704                 1                   0.532156
University of Virgina School of Medicine          0.123755            0.630067                 1                   0.196415
University of Michigan Medical School             0.158465            0.637237                 1                   0.248675
NY University School of Medicine                  0.0822029           0.642516                 1                   0.127939
Tufts University School of Medicine               0.100302            0.644314                 1                   0.155672
University of Massachusetts                       0.19562             0.64686                  1                   0.302414
University of Wisconsin                           0.226581            0.64686                  0                   0.350278
Chicago Medical School                            0.221883            0.648157                 0                   0.342329
Perelman School of Medicine                       0.26908             0.653143                 1                   0.411977
Standford University School of Medicine           0.0780054           0.656658                 1                   0.118791

The top 20 sorted by Median/House and Loweset Tution are:
Name of Institution                               Median/House Price  Tuition Over 8 Years     Has Space Industry? Score

University of Maryland                            0.38124             0.722617                 1                   0.527583
Chicago Medical School                            0.221883            0.648157                 0                   0.342329
University Of Washington                          0.0973689           0.761413                 1                   0.127879
University of Alabama                             0.463577            0.722279                 1                   0.641825
Rutgers New Jersey Medical School                 0.140412            0.722115                 0                   0.194446
Geisel School of Medicine                         0.205529            0.71526                  0                   0.287349
Ohio State University                             0.32499             0.610704                 1                   0.532156
Harvard Medical School                            0.100302            0.710787                 1                   0.141114
Duke University School of Medicine                0.246991            0.66683                  1                   0.370395
Boston University School of Medicine              0.100302            0.710787                 1                   0.141114
Perelman School of Medicine                       0.26908             0.653143                 1                   0.411977
University of Wisconsin                           0.226581            0.64686                  0                   0.350278
University of North Carolina                      0.176684            0.6637                   0                   0.26621
Standford University School of Medicine           0.0780054           0.656658                 1                   0.118791
Johns Hopkins Univerty School of Medicine         0.38124             0.606103                 1                   0.629002
Northwestern University                           0.221883            0.677341                 0                   0.32758
Indiana University                                0.335939            0.501944                 0                   0.669276
Case Western Reserve                              0.211817            0.536384                 1                   0.394898
Emory University                                  0.206169            0.576814                 1                   0.357427
University of Massachusetts                       0.19562             0.64686                  1                   0.302414

The top 20 sorted by Score (Median/House * Tuition/Salary) are:
Name of Institution                               Median/House Price  Tuition Over 8 Years     Has Space Industry? Score

Indiana University                                0.335939            0.501944                 0                   0.669276
University of Alabama                             0.463577            0.722279                 1                   0.641825
Johns Hopkins Univerty School of Medicine         0.38124             0.606103                 1                   0.629002
Ohio State University                             0.32499             0.610704                 1                   0.532156
University of Maryland                            0.38124             0.722617                 1                   0.527583
Medical University of SC                          0.185816            0.354728                 0                   0.523827
University of Utah                                0.140142            0.311285                 0                   0.450205
Perelman School of Medicine                       0.26908             0.653143                 1                   0.411977
Case Western Reserve                              0.211817            0.536384                 1                   0.394898
Duke University School of Medicine                0.246991            0.66683                  1                   0.370395
Emory University                                  0.206169            0.576814                 1                   0.357427
University of Wisconsin                           0.226581            0.64686                  0                   0.350278
Chicago Medical School                            0.221883            0.648157                 0                   0.342329
Northwestern University                           0.221883            0.677341                 0                   0.32758
University of Massachusetts                       0.19562             0.64686                  1                   0.302414
Geisel School of Medicine                         0.205529            0.71526                  0                   0.287349
University of North Carolina                      0.176684            0.6637                   0                   0.26621
University of Michigan Medical School             0.158465            0.637237                 1                   0.248675
Georgetown University                             0.128883            0.604001                 1                   0.213382
University of California, SD                      0.109214            0.531397                 1                   0.205523
```

EDIT 3:

I Greatly Apologize for those who tried to compile this program. It now compiles and runs.

Comment: What's `functionThatCompares`? If it's comparing list elements directly, you might be comparing pointers and not instances of `Schools`.

Comment: Apologies! I forgot to make a note of that, `functionThatCompares` are multiple functions that determine the outcome of how that is to be sorted. For example, if I want the lowest cost of living I write `return a->housing < b->housing`. But I have this for 3 other test cases.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input an output? It's kind of unclear what you want here. As far as I can tell, you have four vectors of data and you want the top 20 something.

Comment: If you want to find intersection, then you can use something like this, a map of string -> tuple(int, school) . Iterate over all the vectors in O(n) after sorting, so suppose you want top 4 schools from each vector and their intersection, then store them in map as u iterate over all the vectors and store the cnt and school object as well. After you are done iterating, just check the count, whoevers cnt = 3 as you are passing three vectors, that is your school which is common. Let me know what do you think, I can then think of the solution in code.

Comment: `auto inCommon;` doesn't work. Please make sure your example compiles and produces the specific problem you are asking about. If you are asking about a compilation error, make sure it produces that error. I recommend you read about [MCVE]s and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have made an edit of one of the functions that compares, the program is rather large so I don't want to have to copy the whole thing into here.

Comment: @Sailanarmo The link I've provided address that concern. We don't ask or expect your entire code base. Your goal should be to find the smallest example that can still reproduce your problem. In any case, it's a strong debugging technique that can often make the problem self-evident.

Comment: @zenwraight I have added example output.

Comment: @Sailanarmo To elaborate, if this is the minimum you can make it, that's ok. My original comment was with regards to making it verifiable. The fact that it contains compilation errors shows me that you didn't take the example and actually try it yourself and puts in doubt how much it actually represents the question you are asking.

Comment: you cannot use `std::set_intersection` here, it requires both sequences to be sorted with the same criteria, you need to use other or come up with your own

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are correct, I have this compiling on one computer, and I re-wrote this on another rather too quickly. Give me about 5 minutes to get all the compiler errors fixed up.

Comment: @Sailanarmo now out of the above output, you want the schools that intersect in your case, in the sense the schools which are present in all the three categories right ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I now have a minimal, verifiable, example. I apologize for the mess that I provided.

Comment: @zenwraight correct! Out of all of those schools, I want the intersection of the schools that do come up multiple times and have one final vector of all the names of the schools that came up in each test case.

Comment: @Sailanarmo your [mcve] is not logically correct, if you use the same comparator you will get 4 identical vectors

Comment: I agree with @Slava you need 4 different comparators for sorting each of the vectors.

Comment: I will add that in right now. I am going to apologize in advance for the length of the code.

Comment: @zenwraight, I have added the four cases now.

Comment: @Sailanarmo use lambdas, that would be much shorter and more readable

Comment: Could you not have each criteria you want to consider to be a function, returning a grade (e.g. in the range [0.0..1.0], then write a function which iterates (once) over all schools (``std::list<RatedSchool> rate( const std::list<School>& schools, std::list<std::function<float(const School&)> >  criteria) { ... } `` ? The grades for the single criteria you could sum up and then eventually sort the schools by max-> min grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like a sort or a set_intersection, you can specify how comparison should be done. If you don't specify anything, `operator<` for the type will be used (if it's defined).

In this case, it seems like you probably want to use [`partial_sort_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) instead of `sort`. This will let you get (for example) the top 10 schools by each sorting.

Then you'll have to re-sort those by name to do the set_intersection.

Then you'll do the set_intersection to get the schools that are common between those collections.

Here's some demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct School
{
    std::string name;
    double housing;
    double tuition;
    int rank;
    int weight;

    // default comparison to use if nothing else is specified:
    bool operator<(School const &other) const { return name < other.name; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<School> schools{
        {"School1", 40.3, 20.0, 3, 6},
        {"School2", 10.3, 10.4, 5, 1},
        {"School3", 33.3, 23.5, 1, 2},
        {"School4", 8.5, 15.5, 4, 8}
    };

    // We specify the size of each of these as 3, so when we do the
    // partial_sort_copy, it'll fill in the top 3 for that category.
    std::vector<School> byHousing(3);
    std::vector<School> byRank(3);
    std::vector<School> byWeight(3);

    std::partial_sort_copy(schools.begin(), schools.end(), byHousing.begin(), byHousing.end(),
                           [](School const &a, School const &b) { return a.housing < b.housing; });

    std::partial_sort_copy(schools.begin(), schools.end(), byRank.begin(), byRank.end(),
                           [](School const &a, School const &b) { return a.rank < b.rank; });

    std::partial_sort_copy(schools.begin(), schools.end(), byWeight.begin(), byWeight.end(),
                           [](School const &a, School const &b) { return a.weight < b.weight; });

    std::sort(byHousing.begin(), byHousing.end());
    std::sort(byRank.begin(), byRank.end());
    std::sort(byWeight.begin(), byWeight.end());

    std::vector<School> temp, commonSchools;

    std::set_intersection(byHousing.begin(), byHousing.end(), byRank.begin(), byRank.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(temp));

    std::set_intersection(temp.begin(), temp.end(), byWeight.begin(), byWeight.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(commonSchools));

    std::cout << "Common Schools\n";
    for (auto const & e: commonSchools)
    {
        std::cout << e.name << "\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Common Schools
School3
```

As an aside, it looked to me like making code using `shared_ptr` was going to add some extra work (and probably not gain enough to care about) so I didn't bother. I also left out the screening/sorting by tuition--it's pretty much just more of the same.

Comment: `std::partial_sort_copy` is a good choice here, I would just replace magic number 3 with a constant

Answer (score 1):

As stated in documentation for [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

> 3) Elements are compared using the given binary comparison function comp and **the ranges must be sorted with respect to the same**.

(emphasis is mine) so you cannot use it with your vectors immediately, you would need to resort them all with one common criteria, for example using `name`, before you apply `std::set_intersection` to them and supply the same comparator to `std::set_intersection` itself

I would create a weight for each school and make it grow exponentially depends on index in each vector, then sum them together and sort based on that value. Ones with smallest win. You can also add a coefficient for increasing/decreasing weight of some criteria in sorting decision:

```
std::unordered_map<std::shared_ptr<Schools>,double> weights;
size_t count = 0;
auto weightCalc = [&weights, &count]( std::shared_ptr<Schools> s ) {
    weights[s] += std::exp( count++ );
};
std::for_each( sortByHousing.begin(), sortByHousing.end(), weightCalc );
count = 0;
std::for_each( sortByTuition.begin(), sortByTuition.end(), weightCalc );
count = 0;
std::for_each( sortByRank.begin(), sortByRank.end(), weightCalc );
count = 0;
std::for_each( sortByWeight.begin(), sortByWeight.end(), weightCalc );

std::multimap<double,std::shared_ptr<Schools>> sortedSchools;
std::copy( weights.begin(), weights.end(), std::inserter( sortedSchools ), []( const auto &p ) { return std::make_pair( p.second, p.first ); } );
```

Then use first n schools from `sortedSchools`

Comment: Thank you for your response but I believe there is some confusion, and I blame that 100% on myself. I already have the 4 sorted outcomes as shown by my example output. What I now want, is all of the names that are in common of every one of those outputs. For example, Median/House has Chicago, Tuition has Chicago, Median/House and Lowest has Chicago, and Score has Chicago. I want that to be in my final output vector, same with Johns Hopkin’s.

Comment: @Sailanarmo "What I now want, is all of the names that are in common of every one of those outputs." all of your vectors contain the same data, just sorted in different order. So intersections of all your vectors would be your original one again.

Comment: It’s hard to read because there are so many in there, but take a look at the header Top 20 sorted by Tuition, University of Utah is at the top. Then take a look at the header top 20 by Median/House and Lowest Tuition, the University of Utah does not appear in the top 20 at all. That is what I am trying to filter out.

Comment: @Sailanarmo so you resize each vector to 20 and then need to find intersection? It is not clear from your code.

Comment: This is correct, again, the program is massive. At this point, I should probably copy paste the whole thing since it is causing more confusion this way. I have 30 schools, I perform 4 different test cases on them. And I get 4 different outputs. With those 4 different, I cut it down from 30 to 20, and now I want to find the intersection of the 4 resized vectors.

Comment: Then just resort resulting vectors with the same criteria before applying `std::set_intersection`